# right derivative of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:(a,b)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose  $D_+f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\geq 0$ for any $x\in (a,b)$. Prove that $f(x_1)\geq f(x_0)$ whenever $x_1\geq x_0$.

How to prove? Thanks.

Comment: Assume the opposite and use the intermediate value theorem to find ever smaller intervals with a negative slope of the secant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.

Here are a few hints:

1. Consider $f|_{[x_0, x_1]}$. It then suffices to show that this function attains its minimum at the left end point of the interval.
2. By considering $f_{\varepsilon}(x) := f(x) + \varepsilon \cdot x$, we can assume that $D_+ f(x) \geq \varepsilon > 0$ everywhere. (How does the statement for $f$ follow from the one for $f_\varepsilon$?)
3. Assume that the restricted function from step 1 assumes its minimum somewhere else (at $\xi \in (x_0, x_1]$) in the interval (why does it assume its minimum at all?). Derive a contradiction to the statement $D_+ f(\xi) > 0$. If you need a further hint, look at the proof of Rolle's theorem.